# How to fix an error when entering a command "flet build web"

Tags: flet

I have a problem when running the command flet build web, I have already looked at all the problems with flutter and dart and I don’t know what to do

I reinstalled flutter sdk, used the upgrade commands, nothing helps
[here the image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8QnY.png)